# How to multiply the two different numpy array with the same scalar

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with different dimensions below:

```
my_array = [np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                      [4, 5, 6],
                      [7, 8, 9]]), 
            np.array([[10],
                      [11],
                      [12]])]
```

I want to multiply it by 2 so that I can get the array below:

```
want_array = [np.array([[2, 4, 6],
                        [8, 10, 12],
                        [14, 16, 18]]), 
              np.array([[20],
                        [22],
                        [24]])]
```

I tried

```
2*np.array(my_array, dtype=object)
np.multiply(my_array,2)
```

The error message is "could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)".

Is there an elegant way to do it in Python?

Comment: You  have a list of numpy array.  For the list, you  need to use a loop `[a * 2 for a in my_array]`.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's broadcasting semantics are intended to apply across arrays of values. What you have is a list (a Python list, not a numpy object) of objects (which *themselves* are numpy objects), and you want to do some operation (in this case, multiply by a scalar) to each of them. This is not a numpy problem, this is a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) operation.

```
list(map(lambda arr: 2 * arr, my_array))
```

or, equivalently with a list comprehension

```
[2 * arr for arr in my_array]
```